# Prove $(a,b,c)=((a,b),(a,c))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

The notation is for the greatest common divisor.  I know that 
$$(a,b,c)=((a,b),c)=((a,c),b)=(a,(b,c))$$

Suppose $g=(a,b,c)$.  Then $g\mid a,b,c$.  Also, $g\mid(a,b),c$ and $g\mid(a,c),b$.  Thus there exist integers $k,m$ such that
$$(a,b)=gk, (a,c)=gm$$
Then
$$((a,b),(a,c))=(gk,gm)=g(k,m)$$
Therefore, since $(k,m)=1$ (otherwise $g$ would not be the greatest common divisor of $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$), $g=((a,b),(a,c))$.

Is this proof okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much simpler using the identities you already know (associativity, commutativity, etc)

$$((a,b),(a,c))\, =\, ((a,b),a,c)\, =\, (a,b,a,c)\, =\, (a,b,c)$$

**Remark** $\ $ By induction, in the same way, one can always "flatten" such gcd expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems okay. This is probably the shortest one. But gonna be large because I am oversimplifying.
Let 
$$a=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\alpha_i},b=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\beta_i},c=\prod_{o=1}^{k}p_i^{\gamma_i}$$
Now $\displaystyle \text{gcd}(a,b,c)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i)}$
and $\displaystyle \text{gcd}(a,b)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i)},\text{gcd}(a,c)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\min(\alpha_i,\gamma_i)}$
So prove the equality we need to prove the fact :
for arbitrary integers(also true for reals) $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ 
$$\min(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\min (\min(\alpha,\beta),\min(\alpha,\gamma))$$
Which is obvious since we may WLOG assume $\alpha\ge \beta\ge \gamma$ and both sides equal $\gamma$. Hope this proof satisfies you.

Comment: Nice.  I actually did a similar proof for a lcm this way, and considered it, but I thought mine would suffice.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Yours surely suffices, this one is something I heart. I didn't mean to say your is wrong or something. Nevermind.

Comment: I know what you meant.  I was pretty confident I was right to begin with, but to see it done another way (especially a way that I also feel comfortable using) was definitely awesome.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lalaloopsy You'll gain greater general insight (and a simpler proof) if you use the gcd laws - see my answer.

Comment: Oh you are welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems OK. A more elegant proof would be to show that $m$ divides $a,b$ and $c$ if and only if $m$ divides $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$, which is fairly routine. Then of course $(a,b,c)=((a,b),(a,c))$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just the one identity you know along with symmetry, and  nothing else, to simplify

$$ ((a,b),(a,c)) = ((a,b),a,c) = (((a,b),a), c) = ((a,a,b),c) = (((a,a),b),c) = ((a,a),b,c)$$

In fact, the associative identity for a binary operator $((a,b),c) = (a,(b,c))$ -- or in its more common expression for operators with infix notation $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot(b\cdot c)$ -- is enough to prove that if you operate on an arbitrary number of things, it doesn't matter how you group them: e.g. if you know that binary gcds are associative, then it automatically follows, e.g., that

$$ ((a,(b,c)),d) = ((a,b),(c,d)) $$

without any fuss. And it means that extending the operator to any positive, finite number of terms is unambiguous: if I write

$$ (a,b,c,d) $$

then it doesn't matter how I group the terms into pairwise gcds, I have to get the same value.

If the operator is also symmetric (more commonly called "commutative" when talking about operations, but "symmetric" -- that is, $(a,b) = (b,a)$ or for infix operations $a\cdot b = b \cdot a$ -- that means you can rearrange the terms arbitrarily.

And thus, I immediately know that it makes sense to just say

$$ ((a,b),(a,c)) = (a,a,b,c) $$

and furthermore, if I instead write it as

$$ ((a,b),(a,c)) = ((a,a),(b,c))$$

this could be proven without ever resorting to ternary or quaternary gcds, just by using the associative and commutative laws.

Comment: Already mentioned - see my answer 5 mins prior.

Comment: I felt it worthwhile to completely avoid the quaternary operator. But I had planned on adding some more content anyways

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to ping @Bill

Answer (score 1):

It's worthwhile to consider a proof that resides entirely within the algebra of divisibility.

The main trick in this regard is that if $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative numbers and you can show $x \mid y$ and $y \mid x$, then it follows that $x = y$

Thus, to prove $((a,b),(a,c)) = (a,b,c)$, you need to prove

- $((a,b),(a,c)) \mid (a,b,c)$
- $(a,b,c) \mid ((a,b),(a,c)) $

To get you started on both points, observe that the definition of gcd means that the second statement is equivalent to

- $(a,b,c) \mid (a,b)$ and $(a,b,c) \mid (a,c) $

The entire proof ultimately boils down to repeatedly writing down statements equivalent to what you're trying to prove until you're left with something obviously true.